# Can you bind a whole object to a CommandParameter in XAML?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a linkbutton inside a listbox that receives a list of objects.  I'm using the ListBox.ItemTemplate and DataTemplate to lay out the listbox items.  Can I bind the entire object that is currently binding to the command parameter of the linkbutton?  I've tried using

`CommandParameter={Binding Data}`

and

`CommandParameter={Binding DataItem}`

but I always get the error in output that 'Data' or 'DataItem' is not a property on said object.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

CommandParameter = {Binding}

It will bind to the current object which used to generate the item

Comment: not really. if you work a lot of xaml tech like xamaran, uwp, wpf, etc... it can be different. {x:Bind or Binding} and sometimes you need to add a period to capture the whole object, {Binding . }